# Facing an issue with Ios Notification which is not receiving at device. Same setup is working fine with Android

Tags: ios, firebase, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, ruby-on-rails-5.1

Using [fcm](https://github.com/spacialdb/fcm) for push notification ios and Android

**Request:**

```
fcm = FCM.new(ENV["FCM_TOKEN"])
options = {data: {message: message}, priority:'high'}
response = fcm.send(device_tokens, options)
```

**Response:**

```
{:body=>
"{"multicast_id":8122297942819980145,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1505802064679190%9310a6bdf9fd7ecd"}]}",
:headers=>
{"content-type"=>["application/json; charset=UTF-8"],
"date"=>["Tue, 19 Sep 2017 06:21:04 GMT"],
"expires"=>["Tue, 19 Sep 2017 06:21:04 GMT"],
"cache-control"=>["private, max-age=0"],
"x-content-type-options"=>["nosniff"],
"x-frame-options"=>["SAMEORIGIN"],
"x-xss-protection"=>["1; mode=block"],
"server"=>["GSE"],
"alt-svc"=>["quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="39,38,37,35""],
"accept-ranges"=>["none"],
"vary"=>["Accept-Encoding"],
"connection"=>["close"]},
:status_code=>200,
:response=>"success",
:canonical_ids=>[],
:not_registered_ids=>[]}
```

**Found few discussion but didn't help**

[issues/15](https://github.com/spacialdb/fcm/issues/15)

[issues/1](https://github.com/spacialdb/fcm/issues/1#issuecomment-223152688)

> passing the options: 'priority': 'high' might solve the issue. **But doesn't work for me.**

Facing an issue with Ios Notification which is not receiving at device. 
 Same setup is working fine with Android.

Please let me know if i'm doing anything wrong here.

Comment: You need configure separate payload for iOS which  will be different from Android.

Comment: @NaumanMalik can you tel me sample payload?

Comment: tried with different payload as well didnt work

options = {data: {message: message, notify_type: notify_type}, priority:'high', notification: { body:'BODY', title:'TITLE' }, mutable_content: true }

same response and didn't receive in device

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initially I faced the same issue, but then after looking for solutions, I found this comment https://github.com/spacialdb/fcm/issues/1#issuecomment-223152688.

The payload should have a notification object with title and body attrs,

`options = {
  notification: {title: "Some Title", body: "Some description"},
  data: {extra_data: {}},
  priority: 'high'
}`

Modifying the options payload like above worked form me.

I have also answered for your issue [here](https://github.com/spacialdb/fcm/issues/33)